# Why viewChild reference on Angular 8 unit test is undefinded

Tags: unit-testing, viewchild, angular8

I am using Angular 8 in my project but I have a problem with the unit-test when I have a component with ViewChild Ref in the unit-test is undefined. any help

I have one component

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-rating-star",
  templateUrl: "./rating-star.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./rating-star.component.scss"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class RatingStarComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("measurementBoxStar") measurementBox: ElementRef;

  constructor(private _render: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._render.addClass(this.measurementBox.nativeElement, newClass);
  }
}
```

and my unit-test for this component is

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    declarations: [RatingStarComponent],
    providers: [
      {
        provide: Renderer2,
        useClass: rootRendererMock
      }
    ]
  }).compileComponents();

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RatingStarComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
}));

it("check Input value for Box in red", () => {
  component = fixture.componentInstance;

  component.ngOnInit();
  fixture.detectChanges();

  component.ngAfterViewInit();
  expect(component.valueStar).toEqual(1.702);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.measurementBox.nativeElement.querySelector("span").innerText)
    .toEqual("1.702");
});
```

when I run the unit-test, I received this error [Error for Jasmine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRajE.png)

Comment: can you share the code for rating-star.component.html

Comment: Hi @ysf I put it below .
`div
    *ngIf="valueStar !== -1 && measurementName === ''"
    class="label pt-4 pv-4 mx-8 label-box"
    #measurementBoxStar
>
    <span>{{ valueStar }} </span>
</div>`

Answer (score 2):

obviously `@ViewChild("measurementBoxStar") measurementBox: ElementRef;` is not returning any elements. it may be because `*ngIf="valueStar !== -1 && measurementName === ''"` evaluates to `false` in tests. So changing your spec as follows should fix the problem.

```js
it("check Input value for Box in red", () => {
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  component.measurementName = "";
  fixture.detectChanges();

  expect(component.valueStar).toEqual(1.702);
  expect(component.measurementBox.nativeElement.querySelector("span").innerText)
    .toEqual("1.702");
});
```

Comment: make sense buddy, I will check it on this way, thank you

Comment: +1. I could not figure out why my mocked child component was always undefined and this clued me in to check if my `*ngIf` conditions were evaluating to true. Spoiler: they weren't!