# Angular 9 Karma-Jasmine test not works properly with ViewChild

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-ng-if, viewchild, queryselector

I use Jasmine to make tests for my application in Angular9. I have a problem with the execution of a test that it should works. I have a file "book-edit.component.html" that contains the view of the page that I want to test, and specifically this part:

```html
<form *ngIf='activeForm == "templateDriven"' #templateForm='ngForm'>
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-6">
            Template-Driven Form
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- "touched" indicates modified -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 form-group title-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input [(ngModel)]='book.title' name='title2' type='text' id='title2' class='title form-control'
                #title2='ngModel' minlength='3' required>
            <!-- in order to prevent an error signal in case of title2 is invalid, is useful to check that client have touch that 
            filed. Initially title2 condition are not valid, but just because client doesn't touch that field. For this reason it
            in enough to add AND clause in with we can check that that field is dirty(when a client text into that field) or toched
            anyay () (AND invalid). Thus, if it is invalid it show the parent div. In a more specific way, it will visualize the child
            div based on the type of error (required or minlenght) -->
            <div *ngIf='!title2.valid && (title2.dirty || title2.touched)' class='invalid-feedback'
                style='display: block;'>
                <div *ngIf='title2?.errors?.required'>
                    Title is required.
                </div>
                <div *ngIf='title2?.errors?.minlength'>
                    Title must have at least 3 characters long.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to test this part of code: in case of title2 contains less than 3 letters, it give me error (and it works,I tried without tests).
Thus I would like to trust it using a test like this (book-edit.component.spec.ts":

```js
  it('should have title error if less than 3 symbols provided',
    fakeAsync(() => {
      component.activeForm = 'templateDriven';
      fixture.detectChanges();
      // get our form on the page by using templateForm. To do this add @ViewChild(NgForm) in book-edit.component.ts
      let form = component.templateForm.form;
      // tick() to say to other engine to go ahead and apply the separtions
      tick();
      form.setValue({
        title2: 'te',
        image2: 'http://test.com',
        description2: 'none',
        price2: 100
      });
      form.controls.title2.markAsTouched();
      debugger;
      //expect(form.controls.title2.errors).toBeTruthy();
      expect(nativeElement.querySelector('.title-group').textContent).
        toContain('Title must have at least 3 characters long.');
    })
  );
```

having the following component (book-edit.component.ts):

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, AbstractControl, FormControl, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

import { BookModel } from "../../models/book/book.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'book-edit',
  templateUrl: './book-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book-edit.component.css']
})
export class BookEditComponent implements OnInit {
  bookEditForm: FormGroup;
  book: BookModel;
  activeForm: string = 'reactive';
  // ViewChild: Property decorator that configures a view query.
  // The change detector looks for the first element or the directive matching the selector in the view DOM. If the view DOM changes, and a new child matches the selector, the property is updated.
  @ViewChild(NgForm) templateForm: NgForm;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.bookEditForm = fb.group({
      //define a group and optionally defide if it is required
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      image: ['', Validators.required],
      description: [''],
      price: ['']
    });
    // subscribe to some changes
    route.params.subscribe(res => {
      if(this.book == null){
        this.book = new BookModel('','','',0);
      }
    })
   }

  submitReactiveForm() {
    let bookData = this.prepareSaveBook();
    this.book = new BookModel(bookData.image,
      bookData.title,
      bookData.description,
      bookData.price
    );
    this.book.save();
  }

  prepareSaveBook() {
    const formModel = this.bookEditForm.value;
    return formModel;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Of course, I put  "@ViewChild" in order allow test to detect changes on the form. In fact, in test I'm trying to put a name with less than 3 letters, just to check if there's an error and the message "Title must have at least 3 characters long." appears. Thus, in the end I tried `expect(nativeElement.querySelector('.title-group').textContent).toContain('Title must have at least 3 characters long.');` to check if now my principal div (in book-edit.component.html) contains also the error message because the *ngIf are satisfied, but don't. It doesn't work,and the console capture just 'Test' value (text in clear throught that div) instead of "TestTitle must have at least 3 characters long.". I dubugged the code and I checked that the form is correctly initialized (title2: "te", title2 is touched and title2 is not valid) but it seems that it cannot read the contains of div unloked by *ngIf, and I don't know the reason why

Comment: This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56675534/9740071